# Como insertar datos en nodejs si ya tenemos la ruta utilizando - NodeJS

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, backend

Tengo un problema a la hora de insertar datos en nodejs a través de las rutas de express.
Como soy novato en NodeJs no tengo idea de como se utilizan bien las rutas y tengo muchas dudas al respecto.
Tengo el archivo -**insertQuestion.js**
En este archivo el código es el siguiente:

```
const insert = {};
const connection = require('../config/connection');
var date = new Date(Date.now());

insert.question = (req, res, data, callBack) => {
  connection.query(
    'INSERT INTO post (id, title, content, fecha, receptor_type_id, author_ref_id, receptor_ref_id, level_id, post_type_id) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)',
    [
      null,
      data.title,
      data.txtArea,
      date,
      0,
      req.app.locals.user.id,
      0,
      0,
      0
    ],
    (error, results) => {
      if(error){
        callBack(error)
      };
      res.redirect('/comentarios/comentario', {title: 'Pregunta'});
      return callBack(null, results);
    }
  );
};


module.exports = insert;
```

(Con el archivo connection no hay problema porque me ha funcionado otras veces)
Estoy llando a una variable global llamada -**user** para insertar el id de quien hace el comentario.
Los demás parámetros los pongo a 0 pero los ire modificando cuando sea necesario.
Como tengo que pasar la ruta al archivo **app.js** para que redireccione o envie los datos mediante post?
Yo he probado así pero no está bien,si alguien puede revisar el código y explicarme en que falla se lo agradecería.

```
var insert = require("./controllers/insertQuestion");
```

Lo he puesto así la ruta que paso en el formulario.

```
...action='/controllers/insertQuestion' method='post'...
```

Aquí está mi duda, como tengo que hacer mediante **post**, **use**... No se que ruta poner ni como pasar el objeto insert.question :S

```
app.post('/comentarios/comentario', insert.question);
```

También tengo la misma ruta /comentarios/comentario utilizando para que pueda acceder a la página web, este sería el código(este funciona sin problemas).

```
app.use('/comentarios/comentario', comentariosQuestionRouter);
```

Gracias de ante mano !

Comment: Diría que más que problemas con nodejs tienes problemas con express (o la librería que sea que estés utilizando para gestionar las rutas), no? nodejs solo es un entorno de ejecución de javascript. La librería que utilizas para el enrutado es otra cosa. Te recomiendo que edites la pregunta y añadas la etiqueta pertinente. Un saludo.

Comment: Sí, tienes razón. Soy novato en esto del Backend. Se algo de PHP pero NodeJS se me escapa por el momento por completo. Gracias por decirme que modifique la pregunta y añada express a las etiquetas. Saludos !

Answer (score 0):

Ya he conseguido insertar los datos en la BBDD.
El código quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var encoder = bodyParser.urlencoded();
```

Importante para poder recibir los datos del formulario definir bodyParser y encoder.

```
app.post('/comentarios/comentario', encoder, insert.addQuestion);
```

Ruta del formulario:

```
...action="/comentarios/comentario" method="post"...
```

Por último el arcivo insertQuestion

```
const insert = {};
const connection = require('../config/connection');
var date = new Date(Date.now());

insert.addQuestion = async(req, res, next) => {
    await connection.query(
      'INSERT INTO post (id, title, content, fecha, receptor_type_id, author_ref_id, receptor_ref_id, level_id, post_type_id) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)',
      [
        null,
        req.body.title,
        req.body.txtArea,
        date,
        0,
        req.app.locals.user.id,
        0,
        1,
        0
      ],
      (error, results) => {
        if(error){
          return console.log(error);
        }else{
          return console.log("Datos insertados");
        }
      }
    );

module.exports = insert;
```

Esto sería todo, espero que le resulte de utilidad a alguien.
¡ Saludos !